# Proving two properties of definite integrals

Tags: calculus

1) Given $f(x),g(x)$ continuous in $[a,b] $ and $g(x)>0$ for every $x\in[a,b]$ . 
Prove that there exists $c\in [a,b]$ such that $\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx = f(c)\int_a^b g(x)dx$ .

2) Let $g(x)$ continuous in $[0,1]$ such that $g(x)\leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$  for every $x\in(0,1]$ . Prove that the equation $x=\int_0 ^{x^2} g(t)dt$ has a unique solution (x=0).

Attempts:

2) If I define $h(x)= \int_0 ^{x^2} g(t)dt - x $ , I get that always $h'(x)\leq 0$ . But how can I prove that there can't be a point for which $h'(x)=0$? (and then use Rolle's theorem)

1) I tried using intermediate value theorem, but nothing worked.

Will you please help me?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (2), $h^\prime(x) = 2x g(x^2) - 1\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{} -1$ since $g$ is continuous (and in particular $h^\prime$ is continuous). So on a neighborhood of $0$, $h^\prime$ is strictly negative, which combined with the non-positivity everywhere else shows that $h$ is only $0$ at $0$.

For (1), let $\alpha=\arg\!\min_{[a,b]}f$ and $\beta=\arg\!\max_{[a,b]}f$. Then 
$$
f(\alpha)\int_{[a,b]} g \leq \int_{[a,b]} fg \leq f(\beta)\int_{[a,b]} g
$$
since $g > 0$. Wlog, suppose $\alpha < \beta$ (in particular, if $\alpha=\beta$ we are done), and consider the continuous function $\varphi\colon x\in[\alpha,\beta]\mapsto f(x)\int_{[a,b]} g$. Now, use the intermediate value theorem to show that there exists $c\in[a,b]$ s.t.  $\varphi(c)=\int_{[a,b]} fg$.

Comment: For more details you can see Bartle's book "Elements of Real Analysis", theorem 23.1.

Comment: @Clement C. : Thanks a lot for your answer ! As for (2) - I agree that $h'(x)\to -1 $ . But why does it show that everywhere else in $[0,1]$ the derivative can't be zero ?

Comment: It could be — but will always be $\leq 0$, hence $h$ is non-increasing. Since $h(0)=0$ and $h$ is strictly decreasing on some interval $(0,\delta]$ (as $h^\prime < 0 $ on this interval), $h(\delta) < 0$, and therefore $\forall x\geq \delta$ we have $h(x) \leq h(\delta) < 0$.
Since $\forall x\in(0,\delta]$ we also know $h(x) < h(0) = 0$, we are done.

Comment: Got it  . Thanks a lot !!!!!!